# How to validate URL to confirm video link in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I tried to validate URL to identify whether it's a video link or not. Before I did it using JS and I used following code.

```
function IsObjectAvailableWithoutPlayer(input) {
input = unescape(input);
if ((input.toUpperCase().search('<OBJECT') != -1) || (input.toUpperCase().search('<IFRAME') != -1)) {
    if (IsFlashPlayerInstalled()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

There is a function called **IsFlashPlayerInstalled()**.

```
function IsFlashPlayerInstalled() {
if (!FlashDetect.installed) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

And there is I used FlashDetect.Installed.I tried it in Angular 6 with IONIC 4. But I could't find a way to do it.